# Copy Text from tmux when another pane is updating

Tags: tmux, copy-paste

In `tmux`, when I try to copy text, I select it using the mouse and want to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. H,owever between selecting and hitting that shortcut another pane is updating (`tail -f` or top something like that) and the selection is lost.

How can I circumvent that behavior?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski sure, I added the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not talking about selecting in `tmux` [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332419/108618) (selection disappears when user releases the button) but rather about [this mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332425/108618) or similar.

Zooming the pane (by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, the same to unzoom later) will hide other panes, so they won't interfere. This method resizes the desired pane, so you may not want this.

Alternatively you can enter copy mode in other panes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> in each interfering pane, quit with <kbd>q</kbd> later) to make them stop updating. This method doesn't resize the desired pane.

Comment: that is exactly the "hack" I'm using right now, not that satisfying :/
I do NOT use the mouse mode.

Comment: @Zarathustra Does the hack allow you to copy?

Comment: sure, it does doing it for years, but its annoying

Comment: @Zarathustra If you revealed this in the question, we wouldn't waste each other's time. The answer may be useful for less demanding users, so it will stay. Unless you edit the question in a way that explicitly rules this out. To get answers that fit you better you definitely should add more details to the question ("I'm using this method, but annoying", "I do not use the mouse mode", anything relevant). In general you shouldn't invalidate existing answers but I won't "retaliate" if it happens here; just leave me a comment so I could delete the answer after you change the question.